# Illegal offset type (Laravel)

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel

Ajax code in laravel with controller:

```
<?php

namespace genericlothing\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use genericlothing\Tienda;
use DB;
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
      public function ajaxBodegasFind(Request $Request)
      {
        $str = "";
        $Tienda = new Tienda;
        $Bodegas = $Tienda->find($Request->ctienda)->bodegas;

        foreach($Bodegas as $Bodega){
          dd($Bodega);
          if($Bodega->estado == "0"){
              $str = $str.'<option value="'.$Bodega->cod_bodega.'">'.$Bodega->direccion_bodega.'</option>';
          }
        }

        return $str;
      }
}
```

Error image:
[image: error img]

Array dd($Bodega):
[image: dd bodega]

I do not understand what's happening, I'm a little desperate...

Comment: Trying to access the collection without foreach. You can access like $ Bodega->collectionName

Comment: Why don`t you convert your collection result to Array using ```->toArray()```. It will make accessing easier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do a search on a new instance of Tienda model which will be empty.

> $Tienda = new Tienda;
>
> $Bodegas = $Tienda->find($Request->ctienda)->bodegas;

Should be something like

> $Bodegas = Tienda::find(some value)

You may need a namespace in front of model name

Edit:
I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you are trying to populate a select from a query. If this is the case you want to use something like

`$Bodegas = Tienda::where(fieldname, value)->get();`

Find(value) will only return one record matching records id field. Hope this helps.

Comment: but if I just leave that, it will not bring me the data I need